# making an exception in java

Tags: java, exception

I am creating a matrix class in java, and the following is the method for adding two matrices.

```
public MyMatrix addMatrix(MyMatrix matB) {
        // if (myR != matB.myR || myC != matB.myC) throw an exception
        MyMatrix res = new MyMatrix("", myR, myC, 0.0);
        for (int i = 0; i < myR; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myC; j++) {
                res.myElements[i][j] = myElements[i][j] + matB.myElements[i][j];
            }
        }
        return res;
}
```

myR is the number of rows and myC is the number of columns in the MyMatrix class.
I want to throw an exception if the number of rows or columns of two matrices are different.
How can I throw an exception in the simplest way possible, without having to create a custom exception or anything else?

I tried
`if (myR != matB.myR || myC != matB.myC) throw new Exception();`
but it didn't work.  Specifically, it is giving the error "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Unhandled exception type Exception".

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", what specifically do you mean?  What error are you getting?

Comment: It says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        Unhandled exception type Exception"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use : `IllegalArgumentException` is a Runtime exception

```
public MyMatrix addMatrix(MyMatrix matB) {
    if (myR != matB.myR || myC != matB.myC) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrices must have the same number of rows and columns to be added.");
    }
    MyMatrix res = new MyMatrix("", myR, myC, 0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < myR; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myC; j++) {
            res.myElements[i][j] = myElements[i][j] + matB.myElements[i][j];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html) is an checked exception type, as it does not extend either [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) or [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Error.html).  Therefore, it needs to be declared in the throws clause of the method signature.  Alternatively, an unchecked exception type such as [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) could be thrown.

```java
public MyMatrix addMatrix(MyMatrix matB) throws Exception {
        if (myR != matB.myR || myC != matB.myC) throw new Exception();

        MyMatrix res = new MyMatrix("", myR, myC, 0.0);
        // ...
        return res;
}
```

or

```java
public MyMatrix addMatrix(MyMatrix matB) {
        if (myR != matB.myR || myC != matB.myC) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        MyMatrix res = new MyMatrix("", myR, myC, 0.0);
        // ...
        return res;
}
```

Per the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-11.html):

> ### 11.1.1. The Kinds of Exceptions
>
> […]
>
> The *unchecked exception classes* are the run-time exception classes and the error classes.
>
> The *checked exception classes* are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are `Throwable` and all its subclasses other than `RuntimeException` and its subclasses and `Error` and its subclasses.
>
> […]
>
> ## 11.2. Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions
>
> The Java programming language requires that a program contains handlers for *checked exceptions* which can result from execution of a method or constructor ([§8.4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.6), [§8.8.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.5)). This compile-time checking for the presence of exception handlers is designed to reduce the number of exceptions which are not properly handled. For each checked exception which is a possible result, the `throws` clause for the method or constructor must mention the class of that exception or one of the superclasses of the class of that exception ([§11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3)).
>
> […]
> The unchecked exception classes ([§11.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1)) are exempted from compile-time checking.